# How can I translate this IDCT function into an OpenCL kernel?

Tags: c, opencl

I have the following four 4 `C` functions for IDCT, thanks to the [help I received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45901912/how-can-i-split-this-function-into-smaller-functions-without-sacrificing-its-fun/45903658#45903658) for a previous question. I wish to translate all of the following functions into OpenCL kernels (and run them on the GPU) but I am struggling to get the desired response for the first function itself.

Function 1:

```
void IDCTforX(int32_t *input, uint8_t *output, int32_t input_inter[64]) {
        int32_t Y[64];
            int32_t k, l;
            int32_t Yc[8];
        for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
            for (l = 0; l < 8; l++)
            {
                Y(k,l) = SCALE(input[(k << 3) + l], S_BITS);
                input_inter[(k<<3) + l]= Y(k,l);

            }
        }

}
```

Function 2:

```
void IDCTfor1dim(int32_t *input, uint8_t *output, int32_t input_inter[64])
{
    int32_t Y[64];
    input_inter= Y;
    int32_t k, l;
    int32_t Yc[8];

    for (k= 0; k < 8; k++)
    {
        idct_1d(&input_inter[(k << 3) + 0]);
    }


}
```

Function 3:

```
void IDCTforY(int32_t *input, uint8_t *output, int32_t output_inter[8]) {

    int32_t Y[64];
      int32_t k, l;
      int32_t Yc[8][8];

      for (l = 0; l < 8; l++)
      {
          for (k = 0; k < 8; k++)
              Yc[l][k] = Y(k, l);

      }


              for (k = 0; k < 8; k++)
                  (output_inter[k]) = Y(k,l);


      for (l = 0; l < 8; l++)
      {
          idct_1d(Yc[l]);
          output_inter[k]= Yc[l][0];
      }

}
```

Function 4:

```
void IDCT_Descale(int32_t *input, uint8_t *output, int32_t output_inter[8]) {

    int32_t Y[64];
    int32_t k, l;
    int32_t Yc[8][8];

//Running the loop for de-scaling separately....
    for (l = 0; l < 8; l++)
           {
               for (k = 0; k < 8; k++)
               {
                   output_inter[k]= Yc[l][k];
               }
           }


       for (l = 0; l < 8; l++)
       {
           for (k = 0; k < 8; k++)
           {
               int32_t r = 128 + DESCALE(Yc[l][k], S_BITS + 3);
               r = r > 0 ? (r < 255 ? r : 255) : 0;
               X(k, l) = r;
           }
       }

}
```

For functions 1 and 2, I included a third variable called `input_inter[64]` because I want to set the variable that is being changed to this variable and so that the changed variable can be transferred from one function to the other.

My OpenCL code for Function 1 looks like this:

```
__kernel void IDCTForX(__global int *input, __global uchar *output, __global int Yin[64]) 
{

 int Y[64];
 unsigned int lin;
 unsigned int k= get_global_id(0);
 //unsigned int l= get_global_id(1);

        if (k < 8)
  {
      for (lin=0; lin < 8; lin++)      
            {
                Y(k, lin) = SCALE(input[(k << 3) + lin], S_BITS);
               Yin[(k <<3) + lin]= Y(k, lin);

            }          
   }
}
```

*Note: I have simplified my programs to direct focus only on parts that are relevant to my question.*

I am calling this kernel from my `.c` code like this:

```
cl_uchar *YCbCr_MCU_ds[3] = { NULL, NULL, NULL};
cl_int unZZ_MCU[64];
cl_int idct_out[8];

//For the third variable
cl_int Inter_DCT[64];

cosX_kernel= clCreateKernel(program, "IDCTForX", &ret);

cl_mem  DCT_Intermediate = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, 64 * sizeof(cl_int), NULL, &ret);

for (index_X = 0; index_X < nb_MCU_X; index_X++) {

  for (index_Y = 0; index_Y < nb_MCU_Y; index_Y++) {

    for (index = 0; index < SOS_section.n; index++) {

        int component_index = component_order[index];

        int nb_MCU = ((SOF_component[component_index].HV>> 4) & 0xf) * (SOF_component[component_index].HV & 0x0f);

        for (chroma_ss = 0; chroma_ss < nb_MCU; chroma_ss++){

         //unpack_block and iqzz...

            /* Set OpenCL kernel arguments */
            ret = clSetKernelArg(cosX_kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&DCT_Input);
            ret |= clSetKernelArg(cosX_kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&DCT_Output);
            ret |= clSetKernelArg(cosX_kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&DCT_Intermediate);

            size_t globalForInverseDCT = 8;

            ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, cosX_kernel, 1, NULL, &globalForInverseDCT, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

            ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, DCT_Intermediate, CL_TRUE, 0, 64 * sizeof(cl_int), &Inter_DCT, 0, NULL, NULL);

            //Executing the other functions normally...

            IDCTfor1dim(unZZ_MCU, YCbCr_MCU_ds[component_index] + (64 * chroma_ss), Inter_DCT);
            IDCTforY(unZZ_MCU, YCbCr_MCU_ds[component_index] + (64 * chroma_ss), idct_out);
            IDCT_Descale(unZZ_MCU, YCbCr_MCU_ds[component_index] + (64 * chroma_ss), idct_out); 
     }

    //Calling the up-sampling function........
    }

     //Color-conversion......

     screen_cpyrect();
     }
```

I expected this code to give me the correct output but I am not getting the correct output. I debugged my code and saw that the third variable in `IDCTforX` was changing in the same way as the regular C code I have for `IDCTforX`.

In my `C` code, I am calling the function normally and I am getting the correct output:

```
for (index_X = 0; index_X < nb_MCU_X; index_X++) {
          for (index_Y = 0; index_Y < nb_MCU_Y; index_Y++) {
            for (index = 0; index < SOS_section.n; index++) {
              uint32_t component_index = component_order[index];
              int nb_MCU = ((SOF_component[component_index].HV >> 4) & 0xf) * (SOF_component[component_index].HV & 0x0f);
              for (chroma_ss = 0; chroma_ss < nb_MCU; chroma_ss++) {
                //unpack block and iqzz...

                 IDCTforX(unZZ_MCU, YCbCr_MCU_ds[component_index] + (64 *chroma_ss), idct_intermediate);
                IDCTfor1dim(unZZ_MCU, YCbCr_MCU_ds[component_index] + (64 * chroma_ss), idct_intermediate);
                IDCTforY(unZZ_MCU, YCbCr_MCU_ds[component_index] + (64 * chroma_ss), idct_out);
              IDCT_Descale(unZZ_MCU, YCbCr_MCU_ds[component_index] + (64 * chroma_ss), idct_out);
              }

              upsampler();
            }


              YCbCr_to_ARGB();


            screen_cpyrect();
          }
        }
```

**Why doesn't my OpenCL code behave in the same way as my C code? What is wrong with my kernel code for `IDCTforX`?**

Comment: Please let me know if I need to improve my question further.

Comment: Apparently, in Function 2, I was assigning the values of `Y` (which contained garbage) to the values of `input_inter` which contained the desired values. After I set `Y` equal TO `input_inter` my code began behaving correctly.